# Cannot read property 'style' of undefined at /script.js:13:15

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why doesn't it count styles and write an error, how can I fix it? It seems that he indicated all the paths correctly, connected styles and scripts, but he either does not read them at all (styles) or displays such an error. Here is the code html, javascript, css.
How can you fix this error? And in general not so?

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src = "script.js">
    </script>
    <TITLE></TITLE>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="cookie_notice">
    This site uses cookies
    <div>
        <a class="cookie_btn" id="cookie_close" href="#close">Agree</a>
        <a class="cookie_btn" href="#politika">privacy policy</a>
    </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    let matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
    "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
    ));
    return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
}
let cookiecook = getCookie("cookiecook"),
cookiewin = document.getElementsByClassName('cookie_notice')[0];    
if (cookiecook != "no") {  
    cookiewin.style.display="block"; 
    document.getElementById("cookie_close").addEventListener("click", function(){
        cookiewin.style.display="none";    

        let date = new Date;
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);    
        document.cookie = "cookiecook=no; path=/; expires=" + date.toUTCString();               
    });
}
```

css:

```
.cookie_notice {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999999;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;  
    color: #FFF;
    background: #337AB7;
    padding: 10px 20px; 
    border-top: 4px solid #BFE2FF;
}
.cookie_btn {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 6px 4px 6px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    background: #337AB7;
    border: 2px solid #BFE2FF;
}
.cookie_btn:hover {
    color: #FFF;
}
.cookie_btn:after,
.cookie_btn:before {
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    left: 50%;
    background: #FFF;
    bottom: -6px;
    content: "";
    transition: all 280ms ease-in-out;
    width: 0;
}
.cookie_btn:before {
    top: -6px;
}
.cookie_btn:hover:after,
.cookie_btn:hover:before {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Take that JS and paste it into here (where is says put here). `window.onload = function(){put-here};`

Answer (score 1):

HTML is read from top to bottom, so the script is called before the rest of the page is rendered.

```
cookiewin = document.getElementsByClassName('cookie_notice')[0];
```

This line of code is accessing a element which hasn't loaded yet resulting in `undefined`. To fix this problem simply place the script tag at right before the closing body tag.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you try to make the  tag at the bottom.
like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <TITLE></TITLE>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="cookie_notice">
    This site uses cookies
    <div>
        <a class="cookie_btn" id="cookie_close" href="#close">Agree</a>
        <a class="cookie_btn" href="#politika">privacy policy</a>
    </div>
</div>

<script src = "script.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

here you go